# Still get the path of my local machine to storage/logs after i've deployed my laravel project on shared host

Tags: laravel

I get this error

> There is no existing directory at
>   "/opt/lampp/htdocs/protech/storage/logs" and its not buildable:
>   Permission denied

after i've deployed my `laravel` project on `shared host`  even after clearing cache.
i've used:

- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan route:cache
- php artisan route:clear
- php artisan view:clear

and still have the same problem.

Comment: you run this command on `shared host` or on your `local `?

Comment: i run those in local host then uploaded the project again

Comment: did you give permission to `storage`  folder  as writable ?

Comment: yes i did and still get the same problem

Comment: and `composer install` and `key:generate`

Comment: no i didn't  i'll make those commands and i'll try again thanks @C2486

Comment: not sure but you may check `.env` file `APP_URL` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following steps

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/protech/storage
```

Which means

```
4 - Is read
5 - Is read/execute (execute is always needed for directories)
6 - Is read/write
7 - Is read, write, and execute.
```

Comment: i already changed the permissions of the storage folder but how is that gonna solve the problem when it referring to another path (my local host path)

Comment: Hi @mohamed please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa